# jQuery: Get value from comma seperated options list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel its very simple, but on mondays it's really hard. ^^

I've some HTML like this (it's fix - can't change anything here):

```
<a class="boxed" href="#foo" rel="type: 'box', image: '/media/images/theimage.jpg', param3: 'title here'">bar</a>
```

To get the value from the rel is easy with var `$(this).attr('rel');` but how do I get the value for image or title inside this list? Sure split will work, but I think there's a better way...

Comment: if you are in control of the code why can't you use 3 `data-*` attributes to store the data like `<a class="boxed" href="#foo" data-type="box" data-image="/media/images/theimage.jpg" data-param3="title here">bar</a>`

Comment: @ArunPJohny don't you mean that you CAN instead of you CAN'T use the data-* attributes?

Comment: I'm searching for a solution without changing the HTML. It's a fix template...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do it, here is one that just uses a regular expression to match the groups.

```
var str = "type: 'box', image: '/media/images/theimage.jpg', param3: 'title here'";
var re = /\s?([^:]*):\s'([^']*)',?/;
var result;
var prop = {};
while ((result = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    prop[result[1]] = result[2];
    str = str.replace(re,"");
}
console.log(prop);
```

Another way making it a JSON valid string and using parse

```
var str = "type: 'box', image: '/media/images/theimage.jpg', param3: 'title here'";
var re1 = /(^|,\s)([^:]*)/g;
var re2 = /'/g;
var json = "{" + str.replace(re1,'$1"$2"').replace(re2,'"') + "}";
var prop = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(prop);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var rel = $('.boxed').attr('rel');
var arr = rel.split(',');
$.each(arr, function() {
    alert(this.split(':').pop());
});
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/25XG5/4/)***

Comment: Thx - this sure works, but I thought for a solution without split. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you splitting with 'image:' first?

Comment: @Populus - splitting the `image: ` first, I was avoiding the loop to get the correct image element from the array.

Comment: @Petra - I guess you could use regex, I am not well versed with it. I'll try to come up with one.

Comment: @Krishna: The downvote was an upvote. ;) And 'm also not very familiar with RegEx, but I'm glad epascarello is.

Comment: Maybe because it is HALF the solution. Yeah, you split them into groups, but what do you do from there?

Answer (score 0):

Split works fine here... if you want an associative array:

```
var str = "type: 'box', image: '/media/images/theimage.jpg', param3: 'title here'";
var arr = str.split(',');
var answer = {};

for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    var values = arr[i].split(':');
    answer[values[0].trim()] = values[1].trim();
}
```

But the regex solution by @epascarello is better than this.